# What is the issue with my code? How do I deal with this error?

Tags: python, argv, sys

I am unable to comprehend why I am getting this error from the code below. Thanks for your time!

```
import sys, os, argparse
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import izip

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--data_loc", type=str, help="folder of training data")
parser.add_argument("--out_loc", type=str, help="location to write files")
parser.add_argument("--n", type=int, default=10000, help="top n chunks get saved")
parser.add_argument("--char", action="store_true", help="char or nah")
args = parser.parse_args()

data_loc = sys.argv[1]  
out_loc = sys.argv[2]
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "make_chunk_vocab.py", line 12, in <module>
    data_loc = sys.argv[1]
```

Comment: The problem is in the file "make_chunk_vocab.py" at line 12. Try run this file alone and see what could be the possible problem.

Comment: You haven't actually told us *what* the error is, only *where*. But you are setting up `parser` to accept `data_loc` as a named argument introduced by `--data_loc`. That means your program is expecting that value to be in `args.data_loc`. But your code is looking for it in `sys.argv[1]`. Using `argparse` and parsing your own command lines out of `sys.argv` are two different approaches. You *can* combine them, but stick to the basics to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have 2 arguments? Debug and see what sys.argv contains before accessing it.